# remove / or replaced with empty space--> all strings and what is inside of it using notepad

Tags: text

I have document with many lines in this format: text
 
How to remove / or replaced with empty space--> all strings and what is inside of it. from **"L1" "1" "LC1"  "**> to  **"L9604" "9604" "LC9604"  "**>
using regular notepad or notepad ++ 7.6.0. or suggestions :D

Thank your help.

Answer (score 0):

please try online tool that replaces strings:
http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/replace-text/

if this doesn't handle your situation, there are many other tools available online:
https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=online+string+replacer&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8